# Theme_clean installation on odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i cant get this thing to work, followed all the steps found on web but still got error that some files could not be located as defined in 'website.assets_frontend' . All files are .less

Comment: Provide us with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `node.js` on your server first. Then install less and its accessories:

```
$ sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

(for Linux). Then make sure you have installed the theme including its dependencies (theme_common and website_less).